# "an average of" vs "on average"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I am trying to write a job application with a sentence about my averaged evaluation. But, I don't know which expression is correct or more appropriate in the formal letter.

1) The overall performance evaluation is an average of 5 out of 6 since the fall 2011.

2) The overall performance evaluation is a 5 out of 6 on average since the fall 2011.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is:

The average overall performance evaluation has been 5 out of 6 since fall 2011.

Comment: This is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

The overall performance evaluation has been 5 out of 6 on average since fall 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little more personal:

---

I have averaged 5 out of 6 on my overall performance evaluation since fall of 2011.